# Same mongo query return different fileds in different mongo servers even though collection is same

Tags: mongodb-query

We have two different servers where mongo is deployed. I exported a collection from one of the server in json format and imported it in the other. Now when I run same find query on both the servers, the server from where the collection was imported returns as expected but the server where the collection was imported returns different values. What could have gone wrong?

Two different Mongo servers, Same collection, Same query, Different results

db.cartridges.find({"cartridge_details.cartridge_name" :"java"})

In one of the servers it returns only those which have cartridge_name as java but in another it returns all .